# How to send Vector over UDP conection in JAVA

Tags: java, sockets, vector

I am trying to send vector object from UDP server to UDP client in Java.

Sending and Receiving string as an object after serializing has been achieved , but I am unable to send or receive vectors. Below is server ide code.

```
public class UDPReceive {


    public UDPReceive() throws IOException {
    try {

      int port = Integer.parseInt("1233");

      int allReceived=0;
      String[] custData=new String[3];

      DatagramSocket dsocket = new DatagramSocket(port);

      byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
      for(;;) {
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

        dsocket.receive(packet);

        String msg = new String(buffer, 0, packet.getLength());
        String msg2 = new String(packet.getData());
        custData[allReceived]=msg;
        allReceived++;
        if(allReceived == 3){
            System.out.println("All Data Received");
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                System.out.println(custData[i]);
            }
            Vector rawData=getTransactions(custData[0],custData[1],custData[2]);
            System.out.println("Vectot size "+ rawData.size());
            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
            sendData=(object[])rawData.toArray();
            allReceived=0;
         }/*if ends here */
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    }
  }
```

Here I want to send back "rawData"  variable to client and receive it, and covert it to vector in client side. I tried using byte[] as well, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you serialize the Vector as an ObjectOutputStream and use ObjectInputStream to get the original Vector.

```
public static byte[] objectToBytes(Object o) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
    oos.writeObject(o);
    oos.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

to reverse

```
public static <T> T bytesToObject(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    return (T) new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)).readObject();
}
```